# Using rxjs timer and observable to substitute http server

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable for my search input, I'd like to test it with a timer or setTimeout rather than using a server.

```
this.definitions = this.searchInput.valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                          startWith(''),
                          debounceTime(500),
                          distinctUntilChanged(),
                          switchMap(value => this.definitionService.searchTerm(value))
                        )
```

How can I return observable with timed next() values in my search service to test the input subscription? I'd like to generate responses x seconds.

```
searchTerm(term: string): Observable<Array<any>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchTerm = (term: string): Observable<Array<any>> =>
  Rx.interval(1e3).pipe(map(() => generateFakeResult(term))
```